# Swift, Add a navigation controller in custom activity indicator

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiactivityindicatorview

My Custom Activity indicator is not overlapping Navigation controller.

### Below is my code

```
     func showActivityIndicator(uiView: UIView) {
        container.frame = uiView.frame
        container.center = uiView.center
        container.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(0xffffff, alpha: 0.1)

         var loadingView: UIView = UIView()
         loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
        loadingView.center = uiView.center
        loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(0x444444, alpha: 0.5)
        loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
        loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        var imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSBundle.mainBundle()
        .URLForResource("synch-loader", withExtension: "gif")!)
        let try = UIImage.animatedImageWithData(imageData!)
        var imageView = UIImageView(image: try)

        imageView.center = uiView.center
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: uiView.frame.width/4, y: uiView.frame.height/2, width: 500, height: 15)

        loadingView.addSubview(imageView)
        container.addSubview(loadingView)
        uiView.addSubview(container)
        actInd.startAnimating()

    }
```

---

```
    func navigationHandling()
     {
              if self.navigationController != nil {
             self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = utility.uicolorFromHex(0x70B420)
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = utility.uicolorFromHex(0x70B420)
           self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
            self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

    }
         sortingBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image: sortingImg,  style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: Selector("sortingPressed:"))

          menuBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image: menuImg,  style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action : nil)
          sortingBtn.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
          menuBtn.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
          var buttons : NSArray = [menuBtn,sortingBtn]
          self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttons as [AnyObject]
         self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([menuBtn,sortingBtn], animated: true)
          networkLabel.hidden = true

}
```

I just want to overlap the view on navigation controller so that it don't looks ugly.

I appreciate help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate
let window = appDelegate?.window
window.addSubview("yourActivityIndicator")
```

Here add the activity indicator to the window, or pass the window in as the view.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate
let window = appDelegate?.window
showActivityIndicator(window)
```

Comment: this code worked before , now for some reason i don t see activity indicator, when I set window.makeVisible I can see it, ...

Answer (score 0):

The uiView you're passing as parameter to this method

```
func showActivityIndicator(uiView: UIView)
```

is your ViewController's view or your UINavigationController's view? 
Because if it's your UIViewController's view your custom loading will take it's size and origin, that is under your NavigationBar

Comment: yes i passing UIViewController's view...What should i do to include navigation controller in it?

Comment: Your navigationController is also n UIViewControllers, so it has an UIView called view, that will maintain a navigationBar and a container for child ViewControllers. So, you can just pass navigationController.view to this method and this loading will be all other views that are inside NavigationController